# Inline completion for GitHub copilot extension in VSCode not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Since I have installed github copilot, the inline feature has not been working.

I have inline completion enabled both in the vscode extension settings as well as the settings.json file but still the inline completion does not show up when I try using it in the editor.

The settings.json file is as below:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\GuptaC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.py": "python"
    },
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": true,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false,
        "python": true
    },
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
    "github.copilot.chat.welcomeMessage": "always",
    "github.copilot.advanced": {}
}
```

The logs show:

```
2024-03-19 09:00:31.830 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-03-19 09:25:32.117 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-03-19 09:50:32.727 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-03-19 10:15:33.485 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-03-19 10:40:34.253 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-03-19 11:05:34.965 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
```

Comment: Make sure you are logged into your GitHub account in vscode and you have subscribed to a GitHubCopilot plan. Then press `Ctrl+Shift+p` and write `Developer: Open Extensions Logs Folder`. Update your question providing informations in `GitHubCopilot.log`.

Comment: please let me know if you need anything else to diagnose this or if anything else has to be updated/edited in the question.